# Finding roots of this polynomial

Tags: polynomials, rootfinding

I have a polynomial, given for parameters $x$ in $\mathbb{R}_+$ and  $\alpha$ and $\beta$ in $\mathbb{R}_+^{n}$ by :

$$P(t) = \sum\limits_{i=1}^n \left\{\left(\beta_i - \frac{\alpha_i}{x} - t\right) \prod\limits_{j = 1, j \neq i}^n (\beta_j - t)\right\}$$

How can i find roots, in function of $\alpha,\beta,x$ ? I have troubles factorising it further..

Edit : As a coment pointed out, since my parameter are all non-zero, this is the same a looking for roots of :

$$\sum\limits_{i=1}^n \frac{\alpha_i}{\beta_i - t} = x$$

Comment: I am afraid that it can not be factorised further

Comment: So my only chance is numerical ?

Comment: I don’t know if this helps, but as long as $\alpha_i\ne0$, the $\beta_i$ are not roots, and you can write $P(t)=\left(\prod_i(\beta_i-t)\right)\left(n-\sum_i\frac{\alpha_ix^{-1}}{\beta_i-t}\right)$. So, you are looking for roots of $\sum_i\frac{\alpha_i}{\beta_i-t}=nx$.

Comment: Yeah it's actualy where i came from. Do you think this form is better ? I'll edit with it.

Comment: There is no formula for the roots for large $n$. But the second representation of the equation (as a sum of simple fractions) permits you to obtain almost any qualitative information that you may need about these roots, how they vary as functions of $x$ and easily find them numerically. Just the graph of the LHS.

Comment: I don't think this helps your goal and you may already know this but your problem is actually equivalent to solving $\frac{Q'(t)}{Q(t)}=x$ where $Q(t)=a\prod_{i=1}^n(t-\beta_i)^{\alpha_i}.$

Comment: If $(\beta_i)_{i=1}^n$ are pairwise distinct, then the sequence $((\beta_i-t)^{-1})_{i=1}^n$ of rational functions is $\mathbb R$-linear independent, which implies that the image of the $\mathbb R$-linear map $\mathbb R^n\mapsto\mathbb R[t]/(t^n),(\alpha_1,\dots,\alpha_n)\mapsto\sum_{i=1}^n\alpha_i\prod_{j\neq i}(\beta_i-t)$ has rank $n$, therefore surjective. In other words, if we fix a choice of pairwise distinct $(\beta_i)$ and $x\neq0$, and let $(\alpha_i)$ run through $n$-tuples of reals, then we can reach any polynomial equation. By Abel-Ruffini theorem, no radical formula exists.

Comment: $(\beta_i)_{i=1}^n$ are pairwise distinct. So, @Yai0Phah, If i understand you correctly, with the right set of parameters all polynomials are reachable. Thanks. Suppose now that i have a polynomial $P(x) = \sum_{i=1}^{n} c_i x^i$. Is it possible to find $\alpha$ and $\beta$ matching this polynomial ?

Comment: What I said is that, even if $(\beta_i)\in\mathbb R^n$ and $x\in\mathbb R$ are supposed to be already given, then by choosing $(\alpha_i)\in\mathbb R^n$, you can reach all polynomials. Now you suppose that all these parameters are positive, you can only reach a cone. But restricted to this cone, it is still true that almost all polynomials (precisely, Zariski dense) are not resolvable by radicals - even the Galois group is $S_n$. I have no proper reference for this statement, but Google will tell us some. Other than the Galois group facts, the rest should be standard exercises for undergrads.

Comment: Sorry, I was careless about the Galois group part. To write down a mathematically precise statement, I should impose that those parameters are rational numbers, and then I claim that the splitting field of the polynomial you want to solve over $\mathbb Q$ is not resolvable (by radicals) for "almost all choices" of $(\beta_i)\in\mathbb Q^n$. I don't know what happens if you also allow not only solution by radicals, but also by elementary functions.

Comment: Thanks for the insights :)